# Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 3.39 (c): Conjugate and minimization.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, conjugate-gradient

The exercise:

> ...Express the conjugate of $g(x) = \inf_z \{ h(z)\mid Az+b=x\}$, where $h$ is convex, in terms of $h^*$, $A$, and $b$.

In the solution manual [here](https://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf), they define $f$ and write

> 

$$f^*(y,v)=\inf (y^Tx-v^Tz-f(x,z))=....$$
However, by the definition of the conjugate, $f^*(y,v)=\sup (y^Tx+v^Tz-f(x,z)).$
So, why this equality holds?

Comment: This looks like a typo but appears to be harmless, since we eventually set $v = 0$.

Comment: Good point. Should be an answer.